# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished within a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm working to create a rake task to remove a few tables and triggers.

My rake task:

```
task :remove_rubyrep do
  sql = <<-SQL
    DROP TABLE rr_logged_events, rr_running_flags, rr_pending_changes;
  SQL
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

I tried running this like so:

```
rake remove_rubyrep
RAILS_ENV=development rake remove_rubyrep
```

Problem is the rake tasks errors with:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

Any suggestions on how to allow the rake task to connect to the DB to execute the raw sql? Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're not loading the rails application in your rake task, so ActiveRecord never creates a database connection.

Change your rake task to:

```
task :remove_rubyrep => :environment do
```

After doing that, you'll no longer need the "establish_connection" line